# How do we get the particular dynamically added td's id in jquery on function

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have dynamic content as follows

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td id='id_1' class='myclass'>1</td>
    <td id='id_2' class='myclass'>2</td>
    <td id='id_3' class='myclass'>3</td>
```

....
and my on function is

```
$(body).on('click','.myclass', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));        
});
```

Now when I click on the td I am getting some integer lets say 671 instead of my td's ID.

Please suggest me the correct way of doing this and what is the wrong with above code

Comment: what do you think `671` is?

Comment: How are the dynamically created element IDs being generated?

Comment: @Reigel I think ID of body

Comment: I'm generating in PHP through Ajax and I checked with firebug the id's are set as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using $('body') instead of $(body)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe $(body) is valid syntax. Try $(document) instead, and it seems to work just fine: [jsfiddle working](http://jsfiddle.net/p9wmL/1/)

```
$(document).on('click','.myclass', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
$('body td').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code and except for the body issue mentioned above it seems to be working well, so your problem must be related to the way that you dynamically add items or the jQuery version that you are using.

Here is code that works with dynamically added items, which is very similar to yours. I'm outputting the selected item to a div just so that it will be more visible.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var counter = 1;
      window.setInterval(function() {
        $('tr').append("<td id='id_"+counter+"' class='myclass'>"+counter+"</td>");
        counter++;
      }, 3000);
      $('body').on('click','.myclass', function() {
        $('#selectedtd').html($(this).attr('id'));  
      });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="selectedtd"></div>
  <table>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using tag selector $(body), so it should be encloed in either single quote ot double quotes. Else go with it-

```
$(document).on('click','.myclass', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));        
});
```